# Access DataGridView data on another form

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a form, Form1, that contains a DataGridView and some text boxes. The DataGridView isn't data bound, as the values are generated from text box input.

I want to use the table data in the Grid View to generate a chart on another form, Form2; how can I best implement this?

So far, I've tried to pass the WHOLE DataGridView from Form1 to Form2 and that didn't work so well-- it removed the whole DataGridView from my Form.

```
//Form1

Form2 MyForm2 = new Form2(this.dataGridView1);
MyForm2.ShowDialog();
this.Controls.Add(this.dataGridView1);

//Form2

protected DataGridView MyDgv;

public Form2(DataGridView dgv)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    MyDgv = dgv;
    this.Controls.Add(MyDgv);
```

Any suggestions? How can I access all of the data from the DataGridView on one form and use it on another?

Thank you

Comment: _"I want to use the table data in the Grid View to generate a chart on another form, Form2"_ - Do you actually need this line then?: `this.Controls.Add(MyDgv);`

Comment: Do you really need the `DataGridView` or the data is is showing?

Comment: @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp I don't necessarily need to DataGridView present on the second form, I just need to be able to access to contents of the DataGridView on the second form to generate a chart

Comment: @John I don't actually need any of that code, I was simply providing an example of what I have tried thus far. That code erases the datagridview from my first form, and places it on the second form which is not what I need. I just need to be able to access the DataGridView data which is on my Form1, on Form 2 so that I can generate a chart with that data.

Comment: _" I just need to be able to access the DataGridView data which is on my Form1, on Form 2 so that I can generate a chart with that data."_ that was the whole point of my question. You said you need to access it, not that you need to display it on your second form. That's why I'm querying that line, since it will actually add it to the controls (i.e. display it) rather than just giving you access to the C# object (which your code without that line does).

Answer (score 0):

- In the Form1, MyDgv "Modifiers" properties make "Public".
- In the Form2, use it:

```
Form1 frm = (Form1)Application.OpenForms["Form1"];
frm.MyDgv // use MyDgv
```

Comment: please add explanation.